# Graph API usage

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, intune

I am unable to use Graph API Beta version API's even though I am an Intune Administrator with licensed MS account. Kindly assist.

What is the exact permission set/access required for me that I can access Beta API's and even execute privileged actions like delete/wipe devices on Intune.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the operations for Intune devices [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-devices-manageddevice?view=graph-rest-beta).

And for wipe action, you need `DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PriviligedOperation.All, DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadWrite.All` Delegated permissions or Application permissions. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-wipe?view=graph-rest-beta#prerequisites).